# Elastic Beanstalk pre-deploy Laravel Node error

Tags: node.js, laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

Issue on Laravel to deploy on Elasticbean stalk as I'm using one of the GitHub packages

https://github.com/rennokki/laravel-aws-eb

and  I dropped the .ebextensions and .platform folders in my root project.

when I deployed and got an error, I decided to check the log report and it said it was due to a node.js

```
2021-10-20 10:48:34,072 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-10-20 10:48:34,079 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2021-10-20 10:48:34,082 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2021-10-20 10:48:34,086 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_Ergnation_rowing
2021-10-20 10:48:34,103 [INFO] Command 00_copy_env_file succeeded
2021-10-20 10:48:36,241 [INFO] Command 01_install_composer_dependencies succeeded
2021-10-20 10:48:36,263 [ERROR] Command 02_install_node_dependencies (sudo npm install) failed
2021-10-20 10:48:36,263 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_Ergnation_rowing: Command 02_install_node_dependencies failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 02_install_node_dependencies failed
2021-10-20 10:48:36,266 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2021-10-20 10:48:36,266 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 02_install_node_dependencies failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 176, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 135, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 561, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 02_install_node_dependencies failed
```

I decided to check file and this file shows

```
02_install_node_dependencies:
    command: "sudo npm install"
    cwd: "/var/app/staging"
```

Seems it look correct method to install node.js

I have tried "`Sudo yum install -y nodejs`" and be deployed again but the console log keeps showing the error `sudo npm install` even I remove it and still showing error npm issue

```
02_install_node_dependencies (sudo npm install) failed
2021-10-20 11:48:45,727 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_Ergnation_rowing: Command 02_install_node_dependencies failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Amazon Linux 2 I recommend you to use [Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html), as you will have more control.

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.config-files):

> On Amazon Linux 2 platforms, we recommend using Buildfile, Procfile,
> and platform hooks to configure and run custom code on your
> environment instances during instance provisioning.

> You can still use commands and container commands in .ebextensions
> configuration files, but they aren't as easy to work with. For
> example, writing command scripts inside a YAML file can be challenging
> from a syntax standpoint

In this case, create the following file in your project

`.platform/hooks/prebuild/install_node_js.sh`

Here is the content of the file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Install  Node  alongside with the paired NPM release

if [[ ! "$(node --version)" =~ "v12" ]]; then   
    sudo yum remove -y nodejs npm

    sudo rm -fr /var/cache/yum/*

    sudo yum clean all 

    curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -

    sudo yum install nodejs -y
fi
```

And that's it, deploy your code and you should have Node up and running.

Comment: Hi Luis, I know this is kinda old, but after searching a lot I don't find anything that works for me. I used the script and still got this error: `[ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Yum does not have npm available for installation`. Any idea on how can I solve this?
Thank you